# How does using a ki focus interact with weapon properties and attack powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons

I understand that when you use a ki-focus/ed weapon to make a [Weapon] attack you use the weapons damage dice and other mundane properties(High Crit, Profieciency Bonus, etc.)while using the ki-focus to provide the enhancement bonus and added critical dice.

I am, however, still unclear about the weapons properties (Carnage, Distance etc.). Do they still apply if you use the ki-focus to provide the enhancement bonuses ?

Also, can you use an Attack Power intrinsic to the weapon but apply the bonuses from the ki-focus when you do (Weapon of Speed) ?

Thanks for the help :

Answer (score 4):

#### When you use a ki focus for a weapon attack, the ki focus' enchantment replaces the weapon's enchantment.

From PHB3, p203:

> Being able to use a ki focus as an implement means you can also use it with your weapon attacks. You can add its enhancement bonus to the attack rolls
> and the damage rolls of weapon attacks you make using a weapon with which you have proficiency. However, you must choose to use the enhancement bonus, properties, and powers of the ki focus, rather than the weapon you're wielding, or vice versa. You can't use both when you use a power.

When you use a power with the *Weapon* keyword, you have to choose whether to use your ki focus's enchantment or the weapon's enchantment for that power. If you choose the ki focus, then its enchantment effectively replaces the weapon's *enchantment* (not its other features) for the purposes of resolving that power.

For example, suppose you have a *+5 Blazing Arc Ki Focus* and a *+2 Superior Crossbow of Speed*. When you use a power that lets you attack with the superior crossbow, you can choose to **treat it** as a *+5 Blazing Arc Superior Crossbow* instead of a *+2 Superior Crossbow of Speed* for the purposes of that attack. It's still a superior crossbow, so it still has a 20/40 range, a +3 proficiency bonus, and the load minor property. It has a +5 enhancement bonus to attack & damage, does +5d6 fire damage on a crit, and can have its damage changed to fire as a free action.

On the other hand, if you use the power granted by the *Weapon of Speed* enchantment to make an attack, then you've already effectively made the choice: it's a *+2 Superior Crossbow of Speed*, because a *+5 Blazing Arc Superior Crossbow* doesn't **have** a power to let you make an attack.

Comment: It is optional to use the magical properties of the ki focus or the weapon.  If you had a high level weapon you might want to use its magical properties instead of those from your ki focus.  However, you might have feats that only trigger when you attack through your ki focus (expertise, etc.).  You are allowed to do both things.  That's one of the things that makes ki focus proficiency a bit overpowered.  You can build your feats up on ki focus and they'll work with any weapon, and if your ki focus is better than your weapon you can choose to use its magic.

Comment: @NickBrown, citation please